# createElement() failing to work on basic path element

Tags: javascript, svg, appendchild, createelement

First, below is the desired result without any JavaScript added

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  transform: scale( 2 );
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba( 95%,95%,95%,0.5 );
  fill: #444;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path 
    d=
      "
       M10 50
       C20 30, 40 30, 50 50
       C60 70, 80 70, 90 50
      "
   ></path>
</svg>
```

Notice the `svg` and `path` elements and the values of the `d` attribute. Everything works perfectly in the snippet above.

In the snippet below, however, we don't have the `path` element yet created so we're trying to insert it with JavaScript. In the completed program the `d` attribute will be filled with dynamic values.

Why doesn't the `path` element show up?

```js
const svg = document.querySelector( `svg` ),
      path = document.createElement( `path` );

path.setAttribute(
  `d`,
  `
   M10 50
   C20 30, 40 30, 50 50
   C60 70, 80 70, 90 50  
  `
)

svg.appendChild( path );
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  transform: scale( 2 );
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba( 95%,95%,95%,0.5 );
  fill: #444;
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

What's more confusing is upon inspection we can see the browser appears to have correctly added the element:

[image]

### How do we get the `path` element to correctly appear in the page using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`createElementNS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS) with the SVG namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector( `svg` ),
      path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', `path` );

path.setAttribute(
  `d`,
  `
   M10 50
   C20 30, 40 30, 50 50
   C60 70, 80 70, 90 50  
  `
)

svg.appendChild( path );
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  transform: scale( 2 );
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba( 95%,95%,95%,0.5 );
  fill: #444;
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Thx ^^. Is this strictly for creating SVG elements only?

Comment: This is used to describe non-HTML objects inside HTML pages. SVG is one of them, but there are others

Comment: This doesn't seem to work the same with `setAttributeNS`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386339/set-attribute-of-basic-svg-element-with-javascript