# Set attribute of basic SVG element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, setattribute, svg-animationelements

First, below is the desired result without any JavaScript added

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
svg { width: 12.5rem; height: 6rem; }
path { fill: none; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 5px; }
circle { opacity: 0.75; fill: #0dd; }
```

```html
<svg>
  <path
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" 
  />

  <circle r='10'>
    <animateMotion 
      dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" 
     />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Notice the `animateMotion` element and values of the `path` attribute. Everything works perfectly in the snippet above.

In the snippet below, however, we don't have the `path` attribute yet added on the `animateMotion` element so we're trying to insert it with JavaScript. In the completed program the `path` attribute will be filled with dynamic values.

Why doesn't the `animateMotion` element work here like in the first snippet when the DOM structure is identical?

```js
let animateMotion = document.querySelector( `animateMotion` );

animateMotion.setAttributeNS(
  `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, `path`, 
  `M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z`
);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
svg { width: 12.5rem; height: 6rem; }
path { fill: none; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 5px; }
circle { opacity: 0.75; fill: #0dd; }
```

```html
<svg>
  <path
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" 
  />

  <circle r='10'>
    <animateMotion 
      dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
     />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Upon inspection we can see the browser appears to have correctly added the `path` attribute exactly as it appears in the HTML of the first snippet:

[image]

Comment: use setAttribute, not setAttributeNS. Only elements are in the SVG namespace, attributes aren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing null as the `namespace` in `setAttributeNS`

```js
let animateMotion = document.querySelector( `animateMotion` );

animateMotion.setAttributeNS(
  null, `path`, 
  `M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z`
);
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
svg { width: 12.5rem; height: 6rem; }
path { fill: none; stroke: #444; stroke-width: 5px; }
circle { opacity: 0.75; fill: #0dd; }
```

```html
<svg>
  <path
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" 
  />

  <circle r='10'>
    <animateMotion 
      dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"
     />
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: even easier if you use setAttribute then you can omit that initial null.